# помогите с кодом. наследование

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

```
class Date {
    public:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

public:

    Date(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        cout << "Year " << year << " " <<  "Month " << month << " " << "Day " << day << endl;
    }


};


class Person : public Date {
public:
    string name;
    string surname;

public:

     Person(int year, int month, int day, string name, string surname) : Date(year, month, day)
   {

         cout << "Birthday"<< year << "." << month << "." << day << "." << endl;
         cout << "Name"<< name << "," << "Surname" << surname << endl;

    }
};
```

При создании Обьекта типа Person

```
int main (){
Person obj2(2017, 23, 9, "Marina", "Said");
return 0;
}
```

СОздается еще и обьект типа Date

```
Year 2017 Month 23 Day 9
Birthday2017.23.9.
NameMarina,SurnameSaid
```

**

Как сделать так что бы при создании обьекта типа Person не вылазил еще в придачу обьект типа Date

Comment: Не наследовать Person от Data? Вообще странно, что персона - это расширенная дата.

Comment: меня волнует не логика, а техническая сторона вопроса

Comment: @MarynaSaid Вы понимаете своей головой, что человек **не является** датой? С наступающим праздником!

Answer (score 1):

Не хотите тянуть за `Person` объект `Date` - уберите наследование, другого пути нет.

При вызове конструктора класса потомка вызываются конструкторы всех его предков.

Comment: Если заменить композицией - все равно конструктор-то будет вызываться...

Answer (score 1):

Объект будет "вылазить", т.е. будет создаваться в любом случае - что при наследовании, что при композиции...

Вам уже говорили, что вы нарушаете сам принцип. Но если ваше наследование вам так дорого...

Вас же на самом деле раздражает не создание объекта - а вывод на экран. Ну отключите его. Вообще выбросьте.

Или добавьте лишний параметр в конструктор - выводить или нет:

```
Date(int year, int month, int day, bool out = true)
{
    if (out) cout << "Year " << year << " " <<  "Month " << month 
                  << " " << "Day " << day << endl;
}
...
Person(int year, int month, int day, string name, string surname)
     : Date(year, month, day, false)
{
```

Или сделайте еще один конструктор - скажем, по умолчанию (кстати, зачем вы сделали все члены `Date` открытыми?) - и руками работайте:

```
Date():yaer(0),month(0),day(0)
{
}
...
Person(int year, int month, int day, string name, string surname)
{
    this->year = year;
    this->month = month;
    ...
```

Все равно после наследования от `Date` от любой затычки *хуже чем есть, уже не будет*...

Comment: "Все, отлазались." П.Санаев "Похороните меня за плинтусом"

Comment: @Igor Мне интересно - это препод тупой и требует именно такого наследования, или студентка упертая? :)